# List of default software versions for given Ubuntu Release

Tags: ubuntu, version

For Ubuntu, is there a website/file which for a given release, e.g. 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver), lists the available (default) version of available software packages?
For example, I want to know which version of `gcc` is shipped with Ubuntu 18.04. Note that I do not have Ubuntu installed on my current system, I just need to know what is available in which version.

Unfortunately I was not able to find this information in the Release Notes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the [Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) website, e.g. [gcc for 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gcc).

Answer (score 6):

A variation of Ignacio's Answer; is you can search for all supported releases in one go with the Ubuntu Packages web site

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc

If you want more detail; you can click on the release of Ubuntu you're interested in and get to the link Ignacio provided..

Answer (score 0):

DistroWatch includes package [versions](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu) for all Ubuntu releases.